# Ubuntu 16.04 won't load nvidia driver

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel, cuda

My kernel is 3.13.0-165.

I installed nvidia-410 from the source of nvidia (http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64).

Here is the output: the installation seemed to be right and the dkms modules was successfully installed.

```
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)

A modprobe blacklist file has been created at /etc/modprobe.d to prevent Nouveau from loading. This can be reverted by deleting /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf.
A new initrd image has also been created. To revert, please replace /boot/initrd-3.13.0-165-generic with /boot/initrd-$(uname -r)-backup.

*****************************************************************************
*** Reboot your computer and verify that the NVIDIA graphics driver can   ***
*** be loaded.                                                            ***
*****************************************************************************

INFO:Enable nvidia-410
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
Loading new nvidia-410-410.79 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.13.0-165-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.13.0-165-generic
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

nvidia_410:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.13.0-165-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia_410_modeset.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.13.0-165-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia_410_drm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.13.0-165-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia_410_uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.13.0-165-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.14) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-165-generic
```

After a reboot, I ran nvidia-smi. It showed that it could not connect to the nvidia driver.

Then I ran modprobe nvidia, here is the output:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_410': Package not installed
```

I checked everything, but I still couldn't get things work.

Please help me find out the problem, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the error message. What does "Package not installed" mean?

Comment: Finally, I installed it with the runfile provided by nVidia. It works.

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by DKMS. The runfile installation can not work if I choose DKMS mode.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I installed the NVIDIA driver by using the run-file provided by nVIDIA. The point is installing it without DKMS. The problem might because of DKMS could not work well with an out-of-date kernel.